# How do I get rid of the <identifier> error in java when I compile this?

Tags: java

Identifier error either has ** or is in bold. I also do not know if the rest of the program will work.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Multi
{
public static void main (String args[]);

**public static String dataIn (Stringinfo)**
    {
        String words = "Your hypotenuse is?";
        String word1 = "Your second side is?";
        String word2 = "Your thrid side is?";
        int a = Integer.parseInt (words);
        int b = Integer.parseInt (word1);
        int c = Integer.parseInt (word2);
        if ((a*a+b*b)== (c*c))
        {   
            System.out.println ("Right triangle") ;

        } 
    }
public static String dataIn (String info)
    {
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(info); return answer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `**` around `public static String dataIn (Stringinfo)`

Comment: You should go back and review the most basic Java tutorials. In particular, read how methods are declared and defined.

Comment: If `words` is `"Your hypotenuse is?"`, then `Integer.parseInt(words);` is not going to end well for you.  You many want to have a call to `dataIn` somewhere in the middle of that (maybe you wanted `Integer.parseInt(dataIn(words));` ).

Answer (score 3):

You are declaring a method `main` like you would in an interface without a body. However, you can't do this outside an interface so `main` must have a body

```
public static void main (String args[]) { }
```

or be removed.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @clcto said about your `main` method not having a body, there is another problem. You need to specify a data type while adding parameters just like when you create variables.

```
public static String dataIn (String Stringinfo)
```

Here `String` is the data type, just like in your other variables. Change `String` to be whatever fits your needs best.

Comment: It is possible `Stringinfo` was intended to be the type, not the identifier, but I suspect there is a missing space and it was intended to read `String info`.

Comment: Whatever it is, the parameter isn't even used in the method!